# "Cannot resolve method 'openFileOutput(Java.lang.String, int)'"

Tags: java, android, io

I'm creating a class with some Read/Write from file functions.

```
String FILENAME = "my_file";
FileOutputStream fos;

public void write(String text, Context ctx)
{
    fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
    try {
        fos.write(text.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But on openFileOutput I get the error "Cannot resolve method 'openFileOutput(Java.lang.String, int)'"

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

Use `ctx` to access `openFileOutput` method in noraml class which is not extending any subclass of `Context` class:

```
fos = ctx.openFileOutput(FILENAME, ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Because [openFileOutput](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) is define in Context class